# standard ml quicksort

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to solve a problem in ml and I'm slightly stuck. forgive me that this is trivial code, but answering it will solve most of my problem.

Code:

```
val sorted = ([3, 2, 1], [5, 8, 4]);
fun loop ([]) = []
  | loop (x::xs) = [3] @ [4];
loop sorted;
```

Error:

```
Error-Can't unify 'a list with int list * int list (Incompatible types) Found near loop (sorted)
Static errors (pass2)
```

Comment: If you find that you now understand the answer to your question and it is not entirely contained in newacct's answer, you can offer your explanation in your own answer. Don't edit his.

Comment: I am fine with that, but for curiosity. Why not?

Comment: Because edits are only intended to let others fix formatting or typos. You were adding meaning, that he may not have intended, to a question that had already been voted on by readers based on its initial contents. On the other hand, it's completely accepted to write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` is a tuple of two lists. `loop` takes a list argument

Comment: so how do I change it to accept a tuple, sorry about my newb type question. I just don't recognize data types in SML yet.

Comment: Basically, the argument to loop should look like a tuple of two things. I don't really know what you want, but probably something like `loop (a,b)` or `loop ([],[])` or `loop (x::xs,x::xs)`. You get the idea.